# How to print from web page without showing print dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I need to implement Web based Point of Sales software where receipt printing will be done often and showing print dialogue every time would be annoying. So I want to get rid of the print dialogue. How it could be achieved using JavaScript?

I have searched a lot on internet and unable to find the proper solution. It has to be supported on all the browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome).

Comment: You can't do this with javascript

Answer (score 2):

Short answer ... You can't ....

Little longer answer ... You can't and probably never will be able to - its just to restrictive to *force* a user to print to a specific printer with specific settings

Comment: This is correct for javascript alone, but they could write a browser add-on which could do this.

Comment: For every browser? By the time you're finished with that you'll have to steal a printer from the museum.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a workaround - this one is not nice.

If you can control the end computer, you can put a simple AutoIt or Autohotkey script on it.
The script can 
1. check if your page is running
2. always apply the standard printer if so.

We have done this for a terminal which shouldn't contain other software then ours. Such things are not nice however if its an unmanaged pc, sooner or later on such devices you will have the problem that someone wants to print something on another printer.